# How to find sum of values in a recycler view

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a list containing some prices in a recycler view. I would like to find the total prices. How would I do it?
below is my list

[image]

Below is the function that I have but it is not working for me

```
 public void total(View view){
    int total_goods=0;
    for (int i=0;i<modelArrayList.size();i++){
        total_goods +=modelArrayList.get(i).getTotal_price();
       
    }
}
```

Below is my code from the receiving of the data

```
public void setCheckout_button(View view){
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner();
    scanner.ScanCode(CheckOutActivity.this);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    //    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    final IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    if (result !=null){
        if (result.getContents() !=null){
            addItemOptions.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            code_input_checkout.setText(result.getContents());
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No results", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}

public void AddStock(View view){
    String code = String.valueOf(code_input_checkout.getText());
    String item = String.valueOf(name_input_checkout.getText());
    String quantity = String.valueOf(quantity_input_checkout.getText());
    String unit_Price = String.valueOf(unitprice_input_checkout.getText());
    String total = String.valueOf(totalprice_input_checkout.getText());
    RecyclerModel model = new RecyclerModel(code,item,quantity,unit_Price,total);
    modelArrayList.add(model);
    recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    Toast.makeText(CheckOutActivity.this, "Data Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner();
    scanner.ScanCode(CheckOutActivity.this);
}
public void FinishAdding(View view){
    addItemOptions.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
public void total(View view){
    int total_goods=0;
    for (int i=0;i<modelArrayList.size();i++) {
        total_goods = total_goods+modelArrayList.get(i);
    }
    
}
```

My model class is below. The getTotal_price method also included

```
public String getCode() {
    return code;
}

public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}

public String getItem() {
    return item;
}

public void setItem(String item) {
    this.item = item;
}

public String getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}

public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

public String getUnit_price() {
    return unit_price;
}

public void setUnit_price(String unit_price) {
    this.unit_price = unit_price;
}

public String getTotal_price() {
    return Integer.parseInt(total_price);
}

public void setTotal_price(String total_price) {
    this.total_price = total_price;
}
```

}

Comment: total_goods is a string....you are doing a string concatenation...not a sum

Comment: I have edited that, tried but still not working for me

Answer (score 1):

replace your method total(); with code below:

```
int total_goods=0;
for (int i = 0; i < modelArrayList.size(); i++) total_goods+= modelArrayList.get(i).getTotal_price();
```

Answer (score 0):

When did you call `total()` function? Before or after `modelArrayList` receive data?

Comment: It is after modelArrayList

Comment: Drop some codes here when you receive data and call total() function might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

**Try**

```
public int total(View view, ArrayList<Integer> modelArrayList){
    int total_goods=0;
    ArrayList<Integer> ma = modelArrayList;

    for (int i=0;i<ma.size();i++){
        total_goods =total_goods + ma.get(i);
       
    }
return total_goods;
}
```

Comment: "Operator "+" cannot be applied to int in model". That's the error I am getting after trying your code

Comment: Assign the modelArrayList to int[] array and get the total OR provide the code of your model's getTotal_price() method